# Why does PowerShell reject my secure string and say it cannot convert it to a secure string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am working on a script that will run `New-RemoteMailbox` with a generated string as the password argument. I have specific requirements for generating the password. It should begin with "Welcome" and then include some numbers and a few acceptable symbols. These are OTPs that will be used shortly after creation so I don't need them to be very strong.

Below is the code where I generate the password and convert it to a secure string:

```
[string]$Prefix = 'Welcome'
$Numbers = -join ((48..57) | Get-Random -Count 3 | % {[char]$_})
$Symbols = -join ((35..38)+(42)+(63..64)+(33) | Get-Random -Count 2 | % {[char]$_})
$Password = $Prefix + $Numbers + $Symbols
Write-Output "Temporary Password: $Password"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $Password -AsPlainText -Force
```

Then here's where I use the variable later:

```
New-RemoteMailbox -Name "$FullN" -Password $Password -UserPrincipalName $Address -FirstName $FirstN -LastName $LastN -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true -SamAccountName $SamName
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-RemoteMailbox], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-RemoteMailbox
```

The rest of this script seems to work without issue. This particular problem only showed up once I introduced the custom password generation (the prebuilt password method often recommended online did not suit our needs, as it generates `(){}[]-./\|=+;:`, potentially needlessly complicating the process for a new user, but the method was not causing this error). I see there have been questions about this particular error before, but the solution to the ones I've seen was using `ConvertTo-SecureString`, which I have in the code. I also can add `Write-Output $Password` any time before the conversion and it seems to output what I would expect (example: `Welcome267#&`).

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have `[string]$Password` in the parameter block, meaning that anything you assign to `$Password` will be converted to a string. Assign the securestring to a different variable, like `$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString...`

Comment: In the process of sanitizing, are you sure in your code example that you don't have quotes around the password parameter like you have with the full name, e.g. `-Password "$Password"`, because that would convert it to a string, and then pass the string to the `New-RemoteMailbox` function.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that did it! I did not know defining a variable with a particular object type would prevent type conversion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @MathiasR.Jessen said in the replies, the issue was that I declared `[String]$Password` (not shown in the question), which prevented it from converting to a secure string. Changing the declaration or just using a new variable both seem to work.